# Drag image within it's parent border?

Tags: silverlight, drag, behavior

I have created image viewer control, that provide zoom in/out the image, and when the image zoomed and be larger than it's viewer (you can't see all the image) I provided the ability to drag the image (**like Windows Photo Viewer**) using "TranslateTransform" but I wanna the image to stop dragging when it's border (left or right or left or down) is appeared, I have done some calculations of the width and height of the fourth sides and it's work fine but when you **speedy** drag the image it stop after **it's border pass it's container border**, and the distance increased by greater drag speed. For example: open an image in "**Windows Photo Viewer**" and zoomed it then drag it it's stop exactly when you reach it's border".

So I wanna the image to stop exactly when it's border appeared regardless of drag speed?

Appreciated your Helps,
Best Regards.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem with your code. Can you just apply range check when you compute parameters for translate transform to avoid moving picture outside the region?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code I have Image(name: imgView), insode grid(name: grdImage), I wanna the image(zoomed image) to move with mouse move in inside the Grid, and when it's borders reach the border of grid to **stop**, exactly like **"Windows Photo Viewer"**. FYI: Im zoomed the image using the scaleTransform:

```
Private Sub imgView_MouseLeftButtonDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    _IsMouseCapture = True
    imgView.CaptureMouse()
    Dim tt = DirectCast(DirectCast(imgView.RenderTransform, TransformGroup).Children.First(Function(tr) TypeOf tr Is TranslateTransform), TranslateTransform)
    start = e.GetPosition(grdImage)
    origin = New Point(tt.X, tt.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub imgView_MouseLeftButtonUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    _IsMouseCapture = False
    imgView.ReleaseMouseCapture()
End Sub

 Private Sub imgView_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If (Not _IsMouseCapture) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim tt = DirectCast(DirectCast(imgView.RenderTransform, TransformGroup).Children.First(Function(tr) TypeOf tr Is TranslateTransform), TranslateTransform)
    Dim vx As Double = start.X - e.GetSafePosition(grdImage).X
    Dim vy As Double = start.Y - e.GetSafePosition(grdImage).Y
    tt.Y = origin.Y - vy
    tt.X = origin.X - vx
End Sub`
```

Comment: Since you call CaptureMouse your control will receive mouse messages even when mouse is outside of the control. You have to validate X and Y coordinate to make sure that you are not moving object outside of area